# C# Outlook VSTO How to export the calendar to ics or vcs file?

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, export, vsto

Hy guys.

Any tutorials here how to export a Calender with a range from 1 Yeahr as a vcs and ics file?

What I already tried:

```
OutlookNS = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");

Outlook.MAPIFolder f = OutlookNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

Outlook.CalendarSharing cs = f.GetCalendarExporter();
cs.CalendarDetail = Outlook.OlCalendarDetail.olFullDetails;
cs.StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 11, 1);
cs.EndDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 31);
cs.SaveAsICal(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\calender.ics");
```

The error what I get:

```
The object reference was not set to an object instance
```

So what should I do please help me :)

Comment: did it now by myselfe ill post the answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that works:

```
        OutlookNS = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.MAPIFolder f = OutlookNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        Outlook.CalendarSharing cs = f.GetCalendarExporter();
        cs.CalendarDetail = Outlook.OlCalendarDetail.olFullDetails;
        cs.StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 11, 1);
        cs.EndDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 31);
        cs.SaveAsICal(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\kalender.ics");
```